# Solving first-order ODE with piecewise component

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, piecewise

I have an ODE I'd like to find an analytical solution to,

$$
    \frac{dZ}{dt}=-\alpha Z+\frac{\beta X^n}{(1+X^n)(1+Z^n)} $$

where

$$ 
    X(t) =
    \begin{cases}
          1 & 1 \leq t \leq 6 \\
          0, & \text{otherwise}\\ 
    \end{cases} $$

I'm interested in the case where

$$
    Z(0) = 0 $$

Here's what I have in Mathematica (I am very new, so I am probably missing something simple):

```
X[t_] := Piecewise[{{1, 1 <= t <= 6}}, 0]
Dsolve[{Z'[t] == -a*Z[t] + (b*X^n)/((1+X^n) * (1 + Z[t]^n)), Z[0] == 0}, Z[t], t]
```

I'm not getting any output or errors (it's just spitting the input back to me). Any suggestions?

Comment: Change `X` to `X[t]` in side `DSolve[...]`

Comment: Also changing `Dsolve` to `DSolve` would help. But do not expect this to be solved analytically.